# Hide quantity and unit price on quotation and invoice print (pdf, etc.) with OpenERP (oDoo)

Tags: odoo

I'm not selling product but services and I would like to know if it's possible to hide the unit price and the quantity when I send/print a quotation or an invoice to a customer with OpenERP (v 7.0).

I just want the final customer to know the price and not all the details.

Do you have any idea how I could do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will hide the unit price of product if product type is service other type will be print in report.

try this code,

```
<para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ line.product_id.type=="service" and removeParentNode('para') ]] [[ formatLang(line.price_unit , digits=get_digits(dp='Product Price'))]]</para>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Odera, Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me where I need to specify this code ?

Thanks

Arnaud

Comment: Hi Odedra, If I understand well, I need to create a custom report using Open office then export it to OpenERP ? Is there not a simple way to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: .rml code don't required that all stuff. Just go to your custom module and their have .rml file and put that code and go to the browser and print report you will get you desire output even you don't required restart openerp-server